# Compare two string if match add into another variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:
I want to add green if name match otherwise grey

```
    var section_name = new Array("Ceilings", "Curtains and fixing", "Door and frame", "Fittings", "Flooring", "Light fittings", "Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills");

    for (var i = 0; i < section_name.length; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < status_clr.length; j++) { //"Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills"
            if (section_name[i] == status_clr[j]) {
                li_color.push("green");
                break;
            }
        }
        li_color.push("grey");
    }
```

It add both green and grey when condition satisfied ...where is the problem?

Comment: You need a flag to check if you hit your `break;`

Comment: just use switch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a flag.

```js
var section_name = new Array("Ceilings", "Curtains and fixing", "Door and frame", "Fittings", "Flooring", "Light fittings", "Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills");
    for (var i = 0; i < section_name.length; i++) { 
        var found = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < status_clr.length; j++) { //"Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills"
            if (section_name[i] == status_clr[j]) {
                li_color.push("green");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            li_color.push("grey");            
    }
```

Comment: It wont work..for the first time it will check `Ceilings` with `Walls and skirting` and then add grey then check `Ceilings` with ` "Windows and cills"` then again add grey

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var has_green = false;
var section_name = new Array("Ceilings", "Curtains and fixing", "Door and frame", "Fittings", "Flooring", "Light fittings", "Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills");

for (var i = 0; i < section_name.length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < status_clr.length; j++) { //"Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills"
        if (section_name[i] == status_clr[j]) {
            li_color.push("green");
            has_green = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(has_green !== true) {
        li_color.push("grey");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help ;).

Answer (score 0):

With the break statement your jump out of a loop. And after that you are in the other loop where grey is set.

You could use else, to pick just one color.

```
if (section_name[i] == status_clr[j]) {
    li_color.push("green");
    break;
}
else {
    li_color.push("grey");
}
```

Comment: I give you an idea you can consider, I am not coding for you. If your code comes past both colors it will use both colors. You can change it by make sure it only picks one color. Example with else.

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag to refer to what happend in inner loop:

```
var flag=false;//initialy set to false
    var section_name = new Array("Ceilings", "Curtains and fixing", "Door and frame", "Fittings", "Flooring", "Light fittings", "Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills");
    for (var i = 0; i < section_name.length; i++) { 
        flag=false;//reset flag
        for (var j = 0; j < status_clr.length; j++) { //"Walls and skirting", "Windows and cills"
            if (section_name[i] == status_clr[j]) {
                li_color.push("green");
                flag=true;//set flag
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==false)
            li_color.push("grey");
    }
```